# NuGet packages not found after sync from GitHub

Tags: asp.net, github, nuget

We (me and three other people) will make an ASP.NET MVC application and use GitHub for version control. We've added some NuGet packages like Unity.MVC5.

Person one has commit and sync the project to the master branch. He's got no problems. The other three people sync the branch but they got problems with the NuGet libaries. See errors below:

> **Error:** This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is `..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props`.
>
> **Error:** Metadata file `D:\...\MarkeOnlineWebsite\MarkeOnline.Website\bin\MarkeOnline.Website.dll` could not be found
>
> **Warning:** The referenced component `...` could not be found.

[image]

**Update:** I've also added [this `.gitignore` file](https://gist.github.com/ZiggyMaes/ecf42b65911dd5b2634813b7d4d3a852).

How could we solve this problem?

Comment: Are you committing the packages folder into GitHub? If thats the case, that's a bad idea to start, you should restore your packages from the sources or the feeds instead of committing to Source Control.